# How to add cropie to an Angular project?

Tags: html, angular, croppie

I am trying to add crooping in my angular project, to achieve something like this (as in official croopie documentation) :

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I've found a link "Croopie for Angular" to follow and is listed below:

https://github.com/allenRoyston/ngCroppie

After I runned command:

```
npm install ng-croppie
```

In my project in folder `node_modules` new folder came: `ng-croppie`, and I moved it out of `node_modules` and in my solutions it looks like this:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Now in this tutorial it says:

> Include ngCroppie module into your project;

But when I tryied to add `ngCroppie` to my `app.module` its simply not recognized...

So I'm wondering how to add this croopie to Angular project?

Any kind of help would be awesome!!

Thanks

Based on mr.void answer, and by following link in examples I get following issue:

Even if I placed croppie folder in a right place?

Comment: angular or angularJS? ngCroppie looks like it is for anuglarJS

Comment: @mr.void for Angular

Answer (score 0):

For angular you could use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-croppie

They also provide an example app:
https://deej81.github.io/ngx-croppie-example/

Comment: how to add slider and stuffs like on photo I provided in question?

Comment: try the demo, the slider appears if you select an image

Comment: I will try this in a 2 hours and I will leave a reply. Thanks for posting an possible answer.

Comment: in this link is a full code of croppie ? https://github.com/deej81/ngx-croppie-example

Comment: Based on your example I get some issue, can you please check edited quesiton. Thanks one more time

Comment: install via npm and just import it like in the example: import { NgxCroppieModule } from 'ngx-croppie';